# Azure Virtual Machine Crashing every 2-3 hours

Tags: azure, crash, azure-virtual-machine

We've got a classic VM on azure. All it's doing is running SQL server on it with a lot of DB's (we've got another VM which is a web server which is the web facing side which accesses the sql classic VM for data).

The problem we have that since yesterday morning we are now experiencing outages every 2-3 hours. There doesnt seem to be any reason for it. We've been working with Azure support but they seem to be still struggling to work out what the issue is. There doesnt seem to be anything in the event logs that give's us any information.

All that happens is that we receive a pingdom alert saying the box is out, we then can't remote into it as it times out and all database calls to it fail. 5 minutes later it will come back up. It doesnt seem to fully reboot or anything it just haults.

Any ideas on what this could be caused by? Or any places that we could look for better info? Or ways to patch this from happening?

The only thing that seems to be in the event logs that occurs around the same time is a DNS Client Event "Name resolution for the name [DNSName] timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded."

Comment: This really sounds like an Azure support issue, not something for StackOverflow (and doubtful you'd fare better at ServerFault, since it seems like a transient service issue).

Comment: Did you think about considering Azure SQL as an alternative if your apps support this scenario ?

Comment: My 2 cents to the same, this issue usually is about the IOPS your disk is offering, may be your IOPS quota is drying up, and that's why the VM dies down, after a while the IOPS quota gets renewed (it renews every hour I believe) and you get your machine back. Happens in AWS and Azure both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a fault with the node/sector that our VM was on. I fixed this by enlarging the size of our VM instance (4 core to 8 core), this forced azure to move it to another node/sector and this rectified the issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Smartest or Quick Recovery:**

Did you check SQL Server by connecting inside VM(internal) using localhost or 127.0.0.1/Instance name. If you can able connect SQL Server without any Issue internally and then [Capture](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-capture-image/) or Snapshot SQL Server VM and Create new VM using Capture VM(i.e without lose any data).

This issue may be occurred by following criteria:

1. Azure Network Firewall
2. Windows Server Update